# How to access the api for git in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to use the vscode git api in one my extension to do git clone and other tasks. Is it accessible from the vscode api ?
The code is present here.. [api](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/a13fdcbf500ec40e6262750415a8f8c8a4ca53da/extensions/git/src/git.ts)

Comment: I was wondering the same... In the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_scm) there are only two (2!) items regarding the git api. 

And when I checked out the code of two of my often used Git extensions ([gitHistoryVSCode](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/gitHistoryVSCode), [vscode-gitlens](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens)), I noticed that the authors coded basic git functionality (like `checkout`, `branch` ec.) from scratch instead of using some already build-in git functionality from VSCode.

Comment: Same here, and apparently no news on this. This open issue on the repo seems to try and make the extension's API available: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31103

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Twitter to the rescue!
I asked there and was pointed to the API definitions here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/git/src/api/git.d.ts

...and an example here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/blob/0068c135d1c3e5ce601c1d5c7f7007904e59901e/src/extension.ts#L53

```
// Import the git.d.ts file
import { API as GitAPI, GitExtension, APIState } from './typings/git'; 

const gitExtension = vscode.extensions.getExtension<GitExtension>('vscode.git').exports;
const api = gitExtension.getAPI(1);

const rootPath = vscode.workspace.rootPath;
const repository = api.repositories.filter(r => isDescendant(r.rootUri.fsPath, rootPath))[0];
```

Comment: what is the import line to import `GitExtension`?

Comment: Could you please clarify this bit of code ? It is very confusing, however, I tried but couldn't get nowhere...

Answer (score 11):

Sample code for using git api in vscode extension :

```js
const gitExtension = vscode.extensions.getExtension('vscode.git').exports;
const api = gitExtension.getAPI(1);

const repo = api.repositories[0];
const head = repo.state.HEAD;

// Get the branch and commit 
const {commit,name: branch} = head;

// Get head of any other branch
const mainBranch = 'master'
const branchDetails = await repo.getBranch(mainBranch);

// Get last merge commit
const lastMergeCommit = await repo.getMergeBase(branch, mainBranch);

const status = await repo.status();

console.log({ branch, commit, lastMergeCommit, needsSync: lastMergeCommit !== commit });
```

You also have to update extensionDependencies in you package.json:

```
"extensionDependencies": [
    "vscode.git"
  ]
```

Comment: FYI, I decided to use simple-git npm module instead of relying on git extension.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the `extension` API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#extensions), to access APIs that provided by another extension:

> When depending on the API of another extension add an
>   `extensionDependencies`-entry to `package.json`, and use the
>   [getExtension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#extensions.getExtension)-function and the [exports](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Extension.exports)-property, like below:
>
> ```
> let mathExt = extensions.getExtension('genius.math');
> let importedApi = mathExt.exports;
>
> console.log(importedApi.mul(42, 1));
> ```