# How to get modified files from Git within a VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

As a practice exercise, I'm trying to make a VScode extension that is similar to the existing VScode source control tab.

Similar to the screenshot below, I want to get a list of all files in the current project that have been modified (the list of files that show up when running "git status"), then display them in a treeview.

How do I query git for a list of all modified files using Typescript and the VSCode API?

[image: VSCode Example Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

To get access to the Git Repos in your VS Code workspace you can utilize the API provided by the Git extension that is bundled with VS Code.

This is a sample extension.ts file to dump the array of changes of the first repo in your workspace:

```ts
import * as vscode from "vscode";
import {  GitExtension } from "./git";


export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

  // Run code when command is triggered. Requires to define a command in package.json...
  // This is one way to make sure, that all other extensions -- especially the Git extension -- have been activated, too.
  // Otherwise getExtension() might return `undefined`.
  let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand("myExtension.myCommandId", async () => {
      
      //Get access to API provided by Git extension that is always part of VS Code
      const gitExtension = vscode.extensions.getExtension<GitExtension>('vscode.git')!.exports;
      const git = gitExtension.getAPI(1);

      //Get list of repositories available in current VS Code workspace
      const repos = git.repositories;

      //Get all changes for first repository in list
      const changes = await repos[0].diffWithHEAD();
      
      //Print out array of changes
      console.info(changes);
  });

  context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}


export function deactivate() {}
```

You'll find other examples in this post: [How to access the api for git in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46511595/how-to-access-the-api-for-git-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 2):

Here, this might help [source-control-sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/source-control-sample) . Also check out [vscode-extension-samples](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples) they really help a lot when making a vscode extension