# VS Code extension passing arguments to git commands

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm building a Visual Studio Code extension and trying to pass argument to a git command but the arguments aren't passed and I still get the command prompt box asking for the branch name. What am I doing wrong?

> vscode.commands.executeCommand('git.branchFrom','myBranch', 'main');

I thought this would bypass user input and go ahead and create a branch called 'myBranch' from the 'main' branch.

Comment: I cannot see that it takes any arguments: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/ce46f445c0f1c3992b78a0e401c6125f1aac7bf9/extensions/git/src/commands.ts#L1757-L1760

Comment: Compare with [`git.deleteBranch`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/ce46f445c0f1c3992b78a0e401c6125f1aac7bf9/extensions/git/src/commands.ts#L1812-L1813) that takes a name and possibly a `force` argument.

Comment: See in particular https://stackoverflow.com/a/60238771/836330 and then `await git.repositories[0].createBranch('myNewBranch2', true);`